# Shadowplay vs. NVenc?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, h.264, cuda

I would like to understand the difference bitween NVidia Shadowplay and NVenc. Both allow you to encode videos in h.264 on the fly, but I understood that the first one use a h.264 dedicated chip alongside the GPU and the other one use the GPU pipelines, like CUDA does. Am I right ?

What's the main differences, performance, quality and how to bench them.

Answer (score 2):

[NVENC](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) is a video encoder API built into Nvidia GPUs (it uses dedicated part of the GPU).

Nvidia ShadowPlay is a recording software which uses NVENC.
(source: http://www.anandtech.com/show/7492/the-geforce-gtx-780-ti-review/3)

Comment: may I ask your source ? :)